# select same records multiple times with one column value changed in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have getting same records multiple times with one column value changed using union like this.

```
Select col1, col2, 'A' as col3
Union
Select col1, col2, 'B' as col3
Union
Select col1, col2, 'C' as col3
```

I want to know if there is any way to do this in single query instead of writing 3 queries. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simple `CROSS JOIN` with the specified `VALUES` should do the trick

```
Select Col1,Col2,Col3
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Join (Values ('A'),('B'),('C') ) B (Col3)
```

Comment: @Prabi Happy it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.name, x.field1
FROM sys.databases d
, (VALUES('A'), ('B'), ('C')) AS x(field1)
```

You should look up the cross join syntax but this is an example off how to do it.

Comment: This would be better with an explicit cross join. Regardless +1 from me as it does work correctly.